# I have two of the same cars in my garage. How can I tell which is which when I call the mechanic?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I have two of the same vehicles in my garage and no others. When I call the mechanic for a car and the list comes up, the both have the same name, how do I know which car is which?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cars appear in an order depending on where they are parked in your garage. So for a 10-car garage, the cars might be ordered like:

> ```
> 10    9
>  8    7
>  6    5
>  4    3
>  2    1
>   DOOR
> ```

<sub>Note: I don't know if that's the exact order but there is an order</sub>

Therefore, the car parked in spot 1 will always be at the top of your list when you call the mechanic. You can use this to:

- Know which car you're calling when you have multiple, by knowing where it's parked in your garage (if it's hard to remember, consider parking one in either spot 1 or 10, and the other in the middle)
- Put the cars you call more frequently or in a rush in a spot at the top so they're easier to access.

In order to rearrange the cars in your garage, look for the blue marker to stand in (usually at the back of the garage). Once there you should have a few options for the garage, and one of them is to rearrange the cars.